# Finding a C# equivalent (that specifies a base parameter) to strtol

Tags: c#, converters, long-integer, strtol

I need to convert a `string` to a `long` in c#. I'm porting a C++ program that currently uses [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to do this. Because [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) defines a `long` data type as a "signed 64 bit integer", I am using the following line of code to do the conversion in C#:

```
long value = Convert.ToInt64(stringVal);
```

My question, however, is how do I specify the base value that `strtol` utilizes, with `System.Convert...` (Do I even need it?)? I know there are other question about the C# equivalent for this C++ utility, but I didn't find any that asked about equating the parameters.

The definition of `strtol` is: `long int strtol (const char* str, char** endptr, int base);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the base parameter to your call.

```
long value = Convert.ToInt64(stringVal, base);
```

where base is the base of the number.

Answer (score 2):

You're close:

```
Convert.ToInt64("abc", 16)
```